# Un-frequent Facebook sign up error with Laravel PHP

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

I have my site coded in Laravel PHP and the function to login with Facebook. It works for some, and not then for others to sign up and login with the Facebook function. When it doesn't work users get a "whoops something when wrong" error.

The same thing happens with posting. It works for some fine and others not at all - they also get a "whoops something went wrong" error after hitting 'post'.

Has anyone else had this, or / and know what the issue could be?

Site: http://www.northlandgrapevine.co.nz/

Thanks

Comment: Check you Laravel log located in `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see what's the error.

Comment: I've uploaded the error log here @Bogdan but i don't understand what the issue is from it, do you?  http://online-exposure.com/ErrorLog.html

Comment: The exception that's being logged is a `TokenMismatchException`, which most likely means you're not using a CSRF token in your forms. You can read the [Laravel CSRF Protection Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection) to see how to include that.

Comment: OK! thank you so much. Will that fix both the login issue and the posting issue, or just the posting issue?

Comment: The posting issue most likely. The Facebook issue might be different, as I see also a few exceptions logged reading _'Undefined index: first_name'_, which are related to the Socialite Facebook provider. If those are indeed the cause of the login issue then it would help to see the contents of `AuthController.php` and `AuthenticateUser.php`.

Comment: OK. Fantastic! Thank you!! I will give it a shot ... One last issue I have with the site ( might ask you seeing as you know a lot about this! ), is that when I upload photos via iPhone 5 all vertical photos flip horizontal automatically once posted. Apparently it happens with Laravel sometimes. Have you had experience with that at all?

Comment: That might be because images taken with phones and cameras contain additional metadata about the image known as EXIF (which can contain information from GPS location to shutter speed and so on). One thing stored there is the orientation based on the phones' gyroscope, which your Photos app knows how to read to display the image with a vertical orientation, but once uploaded that info is not used so you get your images displayed on their side. This is just an assumption but it seems the most plausible explanation, because Laravel doesn't go about messing with your images on its own :).

Comment: OK great, thank you. I will look into all the above and see what I can sort out. Thank you so much. I am not sure how to use this site well, but if I can award you a badge or anything let me know, as very appreciative!